# Stripe Payment Method shows payment incomplete "required_payment_method"

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-method, stripe-payment-intent

Here is my implementation

```html
 const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: body.amount,
        currency: 'gbp',
        customer: customerId,
        automatic_payment_methods: {
            enabled: true,
        },
        application_fee_amount: applicationFeeData,
        receipt_email: `${user.getDataValue('emailId')}`,
        transfer_data: {
            destination: merchant,
        },
        metadata: {
            title: 'title',
            startDate: 'startAt',
            endDate: 'endAt',
            actualAmount: body.actualAmount,
            coupon: couponCode,
        },
        setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
    });
```

I have passed "automatic_payment_methods" as I am not getting Payment Method Id as it is an instant payment, but it always fails and the dashboard shows me required_payment_method. But according to docs payment_method is an optional parameter. How to proceed without payment_method parameter in paymetnIntent?

Comment: It's strange but the above code without the "payment_method"  works if I remove "application_fee_amount".  Something to check into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Payment Method [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods) **must** be provided either during [creation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method) or [confirmation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment) (with Stripe.js) of the Payment Intent in order to facilitate the payment.

How you do this will depend on your integration, but the general recommendation is to collect payment information from your customer using the [Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element) which can then be used with the [`confirmPayment`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment) function.

I'd recommend following the [Accept a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) guide which shows you how to build a full payment integration.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my implementation and added the Payment Method, which worked. They should mention this in the documentation. Changed to checkout session.